# Laravel Livewire text input with 2 submit buttons

Tags: laravel

I have a small problem that I cannot resolve because im new to Livewire

I have a form with a text input with a search button.
The user types a word, press enter and the search button finds the result on database... and with that result I enable the save button.

when the user press enter again I save that word on a table.

the problem later is when the user change that word. I press the enter key again and it tries to save and not to search the word...

how can I reset or something when the text input change? without executing it on every key press?
thanks !!

Comment: Can you give us a portion of the code you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer.. it was not on hydrate or dehydrate.. it was on updated function of the property, where I reset all inputs.

thanks for you and me